# Does metrizability means only the inherit of topological properties?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A topological space X is metrizable if it is homeomorphic to a metric space.
So, while it has a homeomorphism between X and a metric space, it means that they have same topological properties. My question is: does all the importance of metrizability is the inherit of the topological property or it has to be more than that?

Answer (score 3):

If a topological space is homeomorphic to a metric space, then there exists a metric on the topological space itself such that the two spaces are isometric. Therefore, all of the metric-space properties also transfer, such as completeness.

However, one must be careful: the properties only transfer to the topological space *under that metric*. It could also have other metrics for which those properties do not hold.

Comment: By what you say, it means that any metrizable space is itself a metric space! You are saying "If a topological space is homeomorphic to a metric space, then there exists a metric on the topological space itself such that the two spaces are isometric". Have I misunderstood you?!

Comment: Nope, you understood perfectly! That is what it means. But people say "metrizable" instead of "metric" to stress the fact that there could be many different metrics. And that they might be qualitatively different.

Comment: How do you define completeness for a metrizable space using the topology only? I also think Emin has a point -- what is an isometry in this case?

Comment: @Thomas: You don't. This is why I made a point to say that it matters what metric is being used.

Comment: @Thomas We can't. For example, $\mathbb R$ is complete, and $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, but it's not complete!

Comment: Completeness is not a topological property. That's why it doesn't inherit.

Comment: But I'm more confused now! I think a metrizable space needs not be a metric space. @Erik, you say that all metrizable spaces are metric spaces! I'm confused :S

Comment: I'm sorry that you are confused, but it is true that all metrizable spaces are metric spaces; if $\varphi$ is the homeomorphism and $d$ is the metric on the other space, then $d(\varphi(\cdot),\varphi(\cdot))$ is a metric on the topological space.

Comment: A metrizable space is one which admits a metric. If you consider a topological space with such an admissible metric, it becomes a metric space. Every metrizable space can be regarded as a metric space in this way.

Comment: @Eric I think I understand you better now! So every metrizable space can be seen as a metric space with the metric d(φ(⋅),φ(⋅)). This means that topologically seeing every metrizable space is a metric space. BUT generally seeing a metrizable space equipped with a topology may not be a metric space, if a distance is not defined there. Am I right?